# Showing input when testing C program using .sh Script

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have an interactive C program that I want to test using a .sh script.
I created one based on these directions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/how-to-send-input-to-a-c-program-using-a-shell-script, and it works fine but the output on the screen is no good.
I want the input to be shown on the screen and with new lines after the input, the same way it would look if the user entered everything manually. The way it is being shown now is the prompt and then a space and then the next prompt and so on.

I have looked at many different questions but none have provided the answer.
I could just print the input every time from the program itself but that would mean it would print the input even when the user manually enters the data.

I do understand that it happens because the input is coming from a file and not the command line but I still want to get around that.
Is there anyway I could do this? I can't use any external tools because I have to submit this script for a class.

Comment: Have you considered using [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) (or [`pexpect`](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect)) for this?

Comment: I have, but as I mentioned before, I can't use any tools because I highly doubt whoever is grading it will have expect or whatever tool installed already.

Comment: .sh will work with all the linux computers we use at the university so I can safely use that.

Comment: Conditionally echo the output: if the input [`isatty()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html)
then do not echo; if it is not, then do echo the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use bash, and - for instance - your program outputs one line for every line input, then all you need to do from your shell script is:

1. Store your input.
2. Pass it to your program and store the output.
3. Alternately echo every input and output line.

Here's a sample C program, which just echoes any line typed to it, prefixed with "You entered":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char buffer[1024];

    while ( fgets(buffer, 1024, stdin) ) {
        printf("You entered: %s", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If we run if from the terminal, we get this:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./sample
first line
You entered: first line
second line
You entered: second line
third line
You entered: third line
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

(using <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> to terminate the input after entering the third line).

Here's a bash script to simulate that:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pass input to program and store output

input=$'first line\nsecond line\nthird line'
output=`echo "$input" | ./sample`

# Split input and output lines to arrays

IFS=$'\n'
inlines=($input)
outlines=($output)

# Alternately print input and outline lines

for i in "${!inlines[@]}"; do
    echo "${inlines[$i]}"
    echo "${outlines[$i]}"
done
```

which gives the output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./test_sample.sh
first line
You entered: first line
second line
You entered: second line
third line
You entered: third line
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

which is identical to how it looks in the interactive session.

If your program doesn't use a simple line-by-line call and response like this one does, then you'll have a bit more work to do, but if you have all your input and output lines and you know what to expect, then it's doable, because after the program's finished you'll still have access to all your input and all your output, and you can echo them however you need to.